# Load testing using Jmeter of Elastic Search API Queries through CSV

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Load testing using Jmeter of Elastic Search API Queries through CSV

I want to perform load testing using Jmeter of Elastic Search API queries which I will pass through CSV.

Please give me suggestions, what should be things I should Consider before doing that and what kinds of graphs that I should look in to, and what plugins should be installed in Jmeter

Comment: Show some code to see what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Get familiarized with the concept of web applications performance testing, load patterns, performance metrics, etc. See [Performance Testing Guidance for Web Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924375.aspx) as an example reference material
2. Build your test plan "skeleton". Implement requests to web services endpoints using [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers. You may also need to add a [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to send at least [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header. See [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter) article for details.
3. Once done validate your script by running it with 1 virtual user and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener enabled. Check request and response details to see if your test is doing what it is supposed to be doing.
4. If your test works fine - add [CSV Data Set config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to your Test Plan and replace the values you would like to parameterize with the JMeter Variables originating from the CSV file
5. Repeat step 3 with 1-2 users to see whether your parameterization works as expected.
6. Now it's time to configure your load pattern (number of virtual users, ramp-up, test duration, etc.) and run your test
7. Analyze results using [JMeter Listeners](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) and/or [HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer. Here, I just want to confirm, what actually csv file may contain. Can I pass the request API of elastic Search into CSV?

Comment: You can put there whatever you want